# Best approach in moving data from one array to a new array in angular ts

Tags: arrays, angular

```
.subscribe((dataChart) => {
    // console.log(dataChart)
    var forxaxis = []
    
    var cd = [dataChart]
    // console.log(cd)
    cd.forEach(element => {
      forxaxis.push(element.strRequestDate)
      console.log(forxaxis)
    });
    },
```

Im trying to move my data in the first array into a new array so that I can use it with chart.js. but it didnt work.

dataChart contain 2 column of data. i insert dataChart into an array called cd. then i tried to push one of the column from dataChart which is called strRequestDate into a new array called forxaxis but it just didnt work as per expected. the result is as shown in the image attached.

this is how the data look like. it was called by using sharepoint API

[error and the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2G3g.png)

Comment: Please show how is `dataChart` defined. _"dataChart contain 2 column of data"_ isn't clear.

Comment: its a data called from sharepoint using API

Comment: Again, please show the data. You could replace actual information with mock data to avoid confidentiality issues.

Comment: i have attached the data as per log by console. hope it help clearing things up

Comment: You could use `Array#map` as shown by @er-sho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array.map` property here, so you don't need to push data manually from one array to another

I have taken sample data in `dataChart` array for demonstration purpose only.

```
let dataChart = [{strRequestId: 1, strRequestDate: 'ABC'}, {strRequestId: 1, strRequestDate: 'PQR'}];

let forxaxis = dataChart.map(x => x.strRequestDate);

console.log(forxaxis);
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxjt9h?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks. i get an idea from here. its really help